# Mysql 7 cluster 3 machines but 4 nodes what to share?

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I'm reading everywhere that the minimum for a mysql 7 cluster is 3 physical machines, but the cluster exists out of 4  nodes
1 mysql node
2 data nodes
1 management node

So this means at least 1 machine must be hosting 2 types of nodes but I cannot find anywhere which machine shares which nodes.

I've read that sharing MySQL and data nodes is not recommended so then it must be the management node and MySQL node which are sharing a machine?

Could anyone please advice me on this..

Just a small edit: I'm currently setting this up because we now have 1 normal MySQL server and we're pretty much hitting its limit. I'm mainly trying to setup the cluster for performance gain (2 data/MySQL nodes should be faster then 1 right?), expanding it with more server to gain redundancy is next on the list.

Comment: http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/faq.html#11

Comment: Yes that is the recommended amount of nodes if you want full redudancy etc. But it can be run with less while still good enough for production. For example if I check http://thegioinguonmo.com/database-server/mysql/how-to-set-up-a-load-balanced-mysql-cluster-with-mysql-5-1.html I see that he runs the mysql nodes and data nodes on the same machines.. Is this an oke practice to do?

Comment: Depends on your needs. If you're running a mission critical system, then you've now destroyed the purpose of having a cluster - redundancy. The host box goes down, your cluster goes down. If you're just doing development, no biggie. if you're running facebook, there's some Farmville addicts who'd like to speak to you with baseball bats.

Comment: Doesn't a cluster also provide performance scalability? (this is currently what I'm after. Redundancy is next on the list..) I mean 2 data/mysql nodes should be better then 1 right?

Answer (score 0):

You can co-locate the management nodes with the SQL nodes to reduce your footprint to 3 x physical hosts

I would recommend taking a look at the Evaluation Guide (note, opens a pdf) which can talk you through these factors, as well as providing some tips / best practices when moving from a single MySQL node to a fully distributed storage engine such as MySQL Cluster:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/MySQL_Cluster_72_DMR_EvaluationGuide.pdf